# What do tcpsession and ipsession do?

Tags: python, scapy

```
from scapy.all import *

pkt = sniff(offline='packets.pcap', session=IPSession)

pkt.sessions()
```

i copied this from the scapy's documentation and i didn't understand what it does exactly what do `TCPSession` and `IPSession` do ?

Comment: [Documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.sessions.html).

Comment: IPSession allows scapy to handle defragmantation of packets in the IP layer for you, otherwise you might miss packets if for example you try to sniff dns packets that were fragmented (therefor you would have to sniff IP packets, and use IPSession to reasseble the packets and check if it's actually a DNS packet)